# Get a user's Most Recent SoundCloud Track Links

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I've been looking for a way to do this for a while because it seems like their should be one.

I just want to automatically pull the 5 most recent tracks from my SoundCloud page and put them on my website under a 'Newest Audio' section.

SoundCloud even does this themselves. If you go to a specific track, on the right bottom of the page it has a 'More tracks by USERNAME,' take a look:
http://soundcloud.com/goldenstatewarriors/mark-jackson-on-the-dan

The closest thing I have found is this:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id={client_id}
```

But for that you need a client_id, which is for soundcloud apps. I tried registering an app, but when I input the `client_id` given to me into the above, I get a bunch of tracks that aren't mine:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=02db8e29aa2fb5bf590f478b73137c67

I just know there has to be a way to do this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/<USER_ID>/tracks.json?client_id=APP_ID
```

hitting it like this:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/jakuboboza/tracks.json?client_id=APP_ID
```

you get:

```
[{"kind":"track","id":3481075,"created_at":"2010/06/16 12:27:20   +0000","user_id":1187050,"duration":1331,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":15835,"sharing":"public","tag_list":"","permalink":"nl-lul","description":"","streamable":true,"downloadable":false,"genre":"","release":"","purchase_url":null,"purchase_title":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":"","isrc":"","video_url":null,"track_type":"","key_signature"...
```

sort it by `created_at` and profit :)

Cheers! Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I couldn't find that on my own.

Comment: Yep, exactly right. @DougieBear If you're doing this for any arbitrary user, I'd recommend finding out their id and using that instead, since the permalink (eg: 'jakuboboza') can be changed at any time. If this were to happen, you'd start getting 404s for that request.