# Embed latest song SoundCloud

Tags: html, soundcloud

I want an embedded sound cloud player like this page: https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed

But if I upload a new song I want it to change automatically. I didn't find any straight forward answer so was wondering if it is even possible.

Any idea's on how doing this preferably with JS?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you will first have to get the user's latest track's ID, by making a GET Request

This link will help you:

[Get a user's Most Recent SoundCloud Track Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454218/get-a-users-most-recent-soundcloud-track-links)

After you've done this, you just enter the track_ID in this iframe (where i say  [track_id])

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[track_id]&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```